# SQL Update from another table - Massive Screw up

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a SQL table that needs updating based on results from an application form.

However, I have missed the most simplest of things in the where clause, and  managed to overwrite all the table data. Lucky for me we are able to recover this information, however, I made a boo boo and now need to fix it and make it more robust and this is where I need some help.

```
UPDATE VETTING
SET EmploymentStatus = CASE
                           WHEN af.Company_Status = 2 THEN
                               0
                           ELSE
                               CASE
                                   WHEN af.Company_Status = 1
                                        OR af.Company_Status = 4 THEN
                                       1
                                   ELSE
                                       NULL
                               END
                       END, 
    CompanyLtdName = @CompanyId,
    CompanyRegistrationNo = af.Company_Number,
    VATRegistered_Ind = CASE
                            WHEN af.boolVATRegistered = 0
                                 AND
                                 (
                                     af.VATNumber IS NOT NULL
                                     AND af.VATNumber <> ''
                                 ) THEN
                                1
                            ELSE
                                0
                        END,
    VATRegistration = CASE
                          WHEN af.VATNumber IS NULL
                               OR af.VATNumber = '' THEN
                              NULL
                          ELSE
                              SUBSTRING(
                                           REPLACE(af.VATNumber, ' ', ''),
                                           PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REPLACE(af.VATNumber, ' ', '')),
                                           LEN(REPLACE(af.VATNumber, ' ', ''))
                                           - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REPLACE(af.VATNumber, ' ', ''))
                                       )
                      END,
    NoCCJs = af.App_HasCCJ,
    NoCCJsDetails = af.App_HasCCJ,
    NoDrugs = af.App_HasPastConviction,
    NoDrugsDetails = af.App_PastConvictions,
    Work_24Hour_Ind = af.Service_24hr,
    Work_Commercial_Ind = af.Service_Commercial,
    Work_Domestic_Ind = af.Service_Domestic,
    Work_FreeEstimates_Ind = af.Service_Estimates,
    Work_FreeEstimatesExceptIns_Ind = af.Service_EstimatesExclude,
    Cards_Accepted_Ind = af.Service_Credit,
    Insurance_Work_Undertaken_Ind = af.Service_Insurance,
    PLInsurance_Ind = af.Vet_HasPLI,
    PLAmount = af.Vet_PLIAmount,
    PLPolicyNo = af.Vet_PLINumber,
    PLExpiry_Dt = af.Vet_PLIExpDt,
    PLIsCombined = af.Vet_PLI_Employee,
    PLCost = af.Vet_PLICost,
    PLInsuranceCompanyName = af.Vet_PLIProvider,
    ELAmount = af.Vet_ELIAmount,
    ELPolicyNo = af.Vet_ELINumber,
    ELExpiry_Dt = af.Vet_ELIExpDt,
    ELCost = af.Vet_ELICost,
    ELInsuranceCompanyName = af.Vet_ELIProvider,
    ExperienceStartDate = af.Accred_ExperienceStartDt
FROM dbo.ApplicationForm af
WHERE af.Company_ID = @CompanyId;
```

I also need to do use a where clause where the vetting table company id is also matched by @CompanyId and I am having a code blind moment, where I think just a and Vetting.Company_Id = @companyId clause should do it but I am today lost.

Any and all help much appreciated.

Comment: No attempt has been made by you to simplify the query to the smallest example that demonstrates the problem. Please read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly. Copy-pasting large slabs of code into the question and asking us to debug it is not useful to the site and actually off-topic. Please also read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu need to join the two tables:

```
UPDATE V
SET 
  V.EmploymentStatus = ...
...

FROM VETTING V
INNER JOIN dbo.ApplicationForm af
ON af.Company_ID =V.Company_ID 
WHERE af.Company_ID = @CompanyId;
```